# K155ID1 power dissipation

Tags: ttl, power-dissipation, nixie

I build my own nixie clock with four digits (IN-14, 10k anode-resistor) with a seperate K155ID1-IC for each digit (so no multiplexing). Also, I am only using the 0-9 range, so every tube has one digit lit up the whole time. However, the ICs start to get a little bit warm, while I can still barely touch them without getting burnt. I measured an average current of 45mA per IC, which would lead to a power dissipation of ~225mW per IC. This seems too high to me, as the datasheet of the "equivalent" [74141 IC](https://tubehobby.com/datasheets/k155id1.pdf) describes a typical power dissipation of only 55mW which is only a quarter of my power dissipation. So basically my question is if you have an idea what mistake I did, or if one of you also uses the K155ID1 and could provide me with information on their power dissipation.

Kind regards :)

Edit: I have also tried using an 20k anode resistor, power dissipation of the IC does not change

Comment: From datasheet ИН-14 anode current should be in the range 2,5...3 mA (2 mA at pulsed 50 Hz voltage). Discharge voltage is 120...170 V and supply voltage should be >200 V. Looks like overload of both IC and indicator.

Comment: @Vladimir The power supply is a 170V-step-up-converter. As I understand the datasheet, the supply (firing) voltage is 170V, with an absolute maximum of 200V. The maintaining voltage is around 145V. As mentionend in the comment below, the voltage on the resitors is about 25-30V, thus resulting in a current of 2.5-3mA.

Comment: If it turns out that the K155ID1 simply has a higher power dissipation, you can get heatsinks for 16-pin DIP ICs.

Comment: ICs could be defective, it is unknown, from where seller got them, may be from waste bin. You can try to power it on with unconnected inputs and outputs. If they still draw much current, this is defect. You can still use it in non-critical devices. As Andrew Morton wrote, heatsink will help, i saw TTL ICs with heatsinks in some factory devices, but heating was caused by high working frequency and load.

Comment: @Vladimir as mentioned in my comment under the other answer, the current with only the supplies wired up is about 17mA. I have uploaded the schematic to my circuit: https://imgur.com/a/ukUC2VE

Comment: Then seems like it works fine. Every zero input adds 1...3 mA to consumption, and because of previous IC is CMOS, input currents will be even bigger. Where do you measure current? At +5V or at common?

Comment: I measured the current at +5V on the K155ID1 (placed on a breadboard, not connected to the circuit)

Answer (score 2):

The [datasheet](https://www.yumpu.com/nl/document/read/30418766/nixie-tube-driver-k155id1-1551-tube-tester) appears to indicate a maximum Icc of 25mA, same as the 74141.

There are no TTL level outputs to be shorted, so this is a bit of a mystery. Are you sure the anode resistor is 10K?

Comment: I just measured the anode resistors, each of them is 10k. When running, the voltage over each resistor is between 25V-30V so the appropriate current (~2.5mA in the IN-14 datasheet) is present.

Comment: Is the voltage on the 'off' outputs < 60V?

Comment: The off-Voltage is bigger than 60V (about 80V on average) on most of the outputs. On some outputs of one IC however, the off-voltage is approximately 40V.

Comment: If you plug one into a breadboard and measure the supply current at 5V with nothing else connected you should have your answer. Unlike CMOS chips, the TTL parts will not behave strangely with the inputs (or outputs) open.

Comment: I have tested it with only the supplies connected, the current then is 17mA. I have uploaded a picture of the schematic: https://imgur.com/a/ukUC2VE

Comment: That is a really blurry picture but I can make out that you're mixing 3.3V and 5V logic- that can cause current to flow in improper ways if the logic level conversion is not done correctly.

Comment: I have rebuild the circuit on a breadboard (as I did before making a pcb), however I cannot recreate the problem there (current drawn from the IC is in specification). I have also checked the pcb but it seems to be okay. I have noticed that the µC on the pcb is getting a lot warmer than the µC I am using for the circuit on the breadboard, so this might be faulty and causing some problems. I am of course also mixing 3.3V and 5V logic in the test circuit,  which does not seem to be a problem in this case. As the µC (ESP8266-12E) is soldered on directly, I will try again with new µC and pcb.